# Adding & using new fonts on Windows Mobile 6.5 without reset

Tags: winapi, windows-mobile, fonts

**Requirement**: Use a newly added font (copied to \Windows) immediately without the need for a soft-reset.

I have tried `AddingFontResource()` bundled with `SendingMessage(WM_FONTCHANGE)`, but to no avail.

**Background**: I'm developing an application that's shipped as a .cab file which includes several Hebrew fonts with it. At the end of the installation I run a program that handles the registration and which displays several `MessageBox()'s` in Hebrew, but I'm getting boxes instead of Hebrew characters.

All help is appreciated.

Code:

```
AddFontResource(L"\\Windows\\Arial.ttf");
::SendMessage(HWND_BROADCAST, WM_FONTCHANGE, 0, 0);

MessageBox(L"HEBREW CHARS TURN TO BOXES");

pEdit = (CEdit*)GetDlgItem(IDC_CODE);
CFont *pFont = new CFont;
pFont->CreateFont(20,0,0,0,FW_NORMAL,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,L"Arial");
pEdit->SetWindowText(L"BUT HERE THEY'LL LOOK GOOD");
pEdit->SetFont(pFont);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[AddFontResource works fine for me](http://blog.opennetcf.com/ctacke/PermaLink,guid,18c06cd4-f442-46fe-a576-5f323a2ddfb1.aspx).  How are you checking for font availability?

**EDIT**

Check the exact name you are passing to CreateFont - it must match the name being returned by EnumFonts.  I would expect it to be "Arial" from your file name, but that's not a given - it could easily be something else (i.e. something more verbose).

Comment: BTW, at least one good thing has already come out of your answer - I neglected the font file's path **\Windows** in the call to `AddFontResource()`, thinking it was redundant. However, `MessageBox()` still shows boxes. The font I'm adding is `Arial.ttf` for the matter.

Comment: I'm marking this as answer, as it addresses directly to the question of using the new fonts successfully. However, my problem remains, which is that the text in `MessageBox()` still shows boxes, so if anyone know of a solution for that I'd appreciate to know.

Comment: The thing is, that the edit field does work (after studying your link), yet the MessageBox() doesn't.

Answer (score 1):

You should deploy the fonts to the fonts folder: \Windows\Font\